# How can I use a shape key animation in conjunction with soft body?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to inflate an object and then have it turn into a soft body. I have tried doing the 'inflation' with shape keys but when I add a soft body to the mesh it prevents the shape key animation from working.

Is it something to do with baking the animation first?
Is there a way I can have soft body 'turn on' at a specific frame?

- I'm only just getting started with blender. 
  Thanks for any suggestions